# What are some recommended resources and tutorials for learning the VTK library toolkit?

Tags: python, vtk

Apart from the books available from [Kitware](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/book.html), I am looking for some links to any resources that could help in learning the VTK library.  Preferably, with example code and tutorials.  Google results have not been terribly informative for me. So I am asking here for links to VTK resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used vtk on my last project. I used it with C++ though, not python.

I remember the forums, wiki and mailing lists had a lots of useful information and helpful people:

http://www.vtk.org/VTK/project/getinvolved.html

http://www.vtk.org/VTK/resources/applications.html

Comment: http://vxl.sourceforge.net/
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~tgtjr/
http://www.fresco.org/

These related sites might help as well.

Comment: http://www.ivtools.org/ivtools/interviews.html

one more

Comment: http://www.imaging.robarts.ca/~dgobbi/vtk/vtkpython.html

Answer (score 2):

- You can buy the [official books](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/book.html)
- You can check some [free ones](http://www.bioimagesuite.org/vtkbook/index.html)
- You must definitely check the examples at the [WIKI](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples)
- You can look at the [source](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/Tutorial/Step1/Python/Cone.py;h=2d7c9a5712bdcf9d8e51fbd77cdc29be9cd921ad;hb=HEAD)
- This [tutorial](http://tcltk.co.kr/files/simplescript.pdf) is a good intoduction. It is about Tcl but it should be trivial to translate the examples in other languages.
- You can ask at the [vtk-users](http://www.vtk.org/mailman/listinfo/vtkusers) mailing list as `Maggie` suggested.