# Where can i find itk documentation for python?

Tags: python, itk

There is a similar question : [Where can i find vtk documentation for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927352)

I'm using **itk** on python. I'm trying to find something can be used for documentation. The c++ documentation is not useful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For VTK see http://stackoverflow.com/q/942657/623518

Comment: I saw the VTK part, and changed the question. Thanks a lot, Chris :) I'm looking for itk documentation now, do you have some recommendation？

Comment: I have never used ITK I'm afraid. I presume you have seen the [ITK wiki tutorials page](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Tutorials)?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It's very helpful :)